# Does ‘sugarplum’ have the meaning of ‘honey’ or ‘sweetie’?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

There is the following advice for ‘defusing an argument with one word’ in a website:

> In an argument in which the fight systems are fully armed you need to
> provide an abrupt interruption. Have a look at the effect one word can
> make and choose your own:
>
> “God dammit why do you do that?”
>
> "**Sugar plum** why do you do that?"
>
> That single phrase, spoken softly can completely change the flow of
> energy in the conversation. It lets someone know the attack is over,
> communication can continue. Some will of course continue to go off the
> rails, so you'll need to use some judgment.
>
> http://www.learnmyself.com/LT-45/defuse-an-argument-with-one-word

I’ve seen ‘sugarplum,’ the word representing for a candy being used in this way for the first time.

Both OED and Wikipedia define ‘sugarplum’ only as ‘a small round sweet of flavored boiled sugar,’ or ‘a piece of dragée candy that is made of dried fruits and shaped in a small round or oval shape. No other meaning.

Does ‘sugarplum’ have an extended meaning like ‘honey’ or ‘sweetie' as an addressing word?

Comment: I believe "sugarplum" has such a meaning and I guess the reason some newly devised usages cannot be found in current dictionaries is that English is a very dynamic language!

Comment: @Nate: As Blessed Geek's answer explains, usages like this aren't typically listed in dictionaries anyway, unless they become *exceptionally* common and remain current for a long time. I'd be surprised if any dictionary listed [lambchop](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hi+lambchop%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as a term of endearment, but it's certainly familiar to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a tradition in English (and many languages) to use fruits and condiments to describe an especially endearing (or repulsive) person or situation.

For example the 1965 Motown hit song "[Sugar Pie, Honey Bunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_Pie,_Honey_Bunch)":
http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/temptations/sugarpiehoneybunch.html.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uwh2QloOnS0.

These are for your personal pleasure and decision to interpret adhoc. There is no precedence to be comparative of which is more intense, but if you wish to compare, you would compare to your personal taste and sentiments. I believe this is true in any language which would use food as allegories.

- honey pie
- sweetie pie
- honey bunny
- apple of my eye

You could even concoct your own, according to your own sentiment, that no one else has used before. e.g., "You stink like a rotten old pineapple". When you did that at the spur of the moment, would you even have considered comparing it to "You smell like a garbage can"? I would not think so. Would you be able to find your newly minted idiom in a dictionary? I would not think so either.

For example, if someone called you "watermelon head", would you find it in a dictionary, idiom book or thesaurus? I don't think so. It is up to you to interpret. I know I would not like to be called watermelon head, or fruit cake, or dip-stick. May be in some unknown culture, being a watermelon head is a good sentiment. Who knows?

I found a list of food idioms [here](http://www.idiomconnection.com/food.html). Some in the list are interpreted according the web site author's personal sentiments and may not reflect the actual traditional meaning.

For example, "Salt of the earth" is interpreted by the author (who probably had no Christian biblical background knowledge) as "good/basic/honest/ordinary people". Actually, that phrase, used by Jesus in the Christian Bible, is frequently interpreted as Jesus telling his disciples that they are the purifying elements, essential condiments to preserve the essence and functionality of society.

Comment: I could never get my head around the French [ma petite choufleur](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ma+petite+choufleure%22&oq=%22ma+petite+choufleure%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.974j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22ma+petite+choufleur%22). Who the hell wants to be likened to a *cauliflower*, fer crissakes!

Comment: Another odd term of endearment that seems to have grown more widespread in recent years (in the United States) is "pumpkin." On the other hand, "my darling gourd" is rarely heard.

Comment: Blessed Geek.I find the list of food idioms you provided me very intriguing as well as useful. It greatly helps me in enriching the stock of English idioms related with foods.

Answer (score 2):

While not a commonly used word, sugarplum definitely has a similar meaning to words like 'honey' and 'sweetie'.  It makes sense that OED and Wikipedia only have the literal definition as the familial term is slang.  I have heard sugarplum used in the way you are describing it many times.

Answer (score 0):

The use of *sugar plum* to mean *honey* or *sweetie* is common in popular music. For example, Ike Clanton had a minor hit in 1962 with a song called "Sugar Plum." The Collins Kids recorded a different song by the same title in the late '50s.